# Symfony3 Rename file PHP

Tags: php, file, symfony, file-rename

I'm trying to rename a file but I get a warning and the file is not renamed.
The error:

> Warning:
>   rename(C:\wamp\www\MyApp\app/../web/uploads/documents\old_name.jpg,C:\wamp\www\MyApp\app/../web/uploads/documents\new_name.jpg):

My code:

```
rename($this->getParameter('document_directory')."/".$oldDocument->getName(), $this->getParameter('document_directory')."/".$documentNewName);
```

Which become:

> 'rename(C:\wamp\www\MyApp\app/../web/uploads/documents\old_name.jpg,C:\wamp\www\MyApp\app/../web/uploads/documents\new_name.jpg): '

I have no more information.

Notice that this code worked for the upload:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['form']['tmp_name']['Document'], $this->getParameter('document_directory')."/old_name.jpg"
```

Comment: What does `var_dump(is_file($this->getParameter('document_directory')."/".$oldDocument->getName()))` return?

Comment: You've removed the most important thing from the warning message. Right after `:` sign there's the reason of the problem. I guess that the `new_name.jpg` already exists.

Comment: The rest of the error is "at C:\wamp\www\LinkWebCRM\src\CommonBundle\Controller\DefaultController.php line 664 ", which is the line of the rename.

Comment: Okay it might have been because $document->getName() is not really working, using an other variable $name = $document->name solved the problem. However, even if now it's working is_file return false...